# The behavior of the trajectory of the phase portrait

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

For the plane autonomous system
$$ x' = ax+by $$
$$ y' = cx+dy $$
If the solution to this system is, say, $  \binom{x}{y}= c_{1}\binom{1}{1}e^{-5t} + c_{2}\binom{1}{2}e^{-t} $, then it is understandable that as $t\rightarrow \infty$, the trajectory will approach the line $y=2x$ as the term $c_{2}\binom{1}{2}e^{-t}$ dominates the solution. As we can see from
$$ \binom{x}{y}= c_{1}\binom{1}{1}e^{-5t} + c_{2}\binom{1}{2}e^{-t} = e^{-t}\left[ c_{1}\binom{1}{1}e^{-4t} + c_{2}\binom{1}{2} \right] $$

However, I was just wondering the case when both eigenvalues are positive. Specifically, if the solution to the same system is

$$ \binom{x}{y}= c_{1}\binom{1}{1}e^{5t} + c_{2}\binom{1}{2}e^{t} $$

**So my question is :**

> Why doesn't the trajectory approach the line $y=x$ when $t\rightarrow
>  \infty$, as the term $c_{1}\binom{1}{1}e^{5t}$ dominates the solution?
>   As we may see this from $$ \binom{x}{y}= c_{1}\binom{1}{1}e^{5t} +
>  c_{2}\binom{1}{2}e^{t} = e^{5t}\left[ c_{1}\binom{1}{1} +
>  c_{2}\binom{1}{2}e^{-4t} \right] $$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed:

When you take your limit $t\to\infty$ you assume that 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{5t}(c_1+c_2 e^{-{4t}})=c_1e^{5t},
$$
which is obviously not correct.

Comment: But shouldn't it be that, in my example, $$ x(t)=e^{5t}(c_1 + c_2e^{-4t}) $$ $$ y(t)=e^{5t}(c_1+2c_2e^{-4t}) $$
and with $t \rightarrow \infty$, both $x$ and $y$ become $c_1e^{5t}$. And this means that the solution approaches the line $y=x$?

Comment: I don't quite see it clearly why the idea in the case $$ x(t)=e^{-t}(c_1e^{-4t} + c_2) $$ $$ y(t)=e^{-t}(c_1e^{-4t}+2c_2) $$
as when $t \rightarrow \infty$ works fine. As we can see that $x$ and $y$ become $c_2e^{-t}$ and $2c_2e^{-t}$ respectively as $t \rightarrow \infty$, and thus the solution approaches the line $y=2x$.

Comment: Please see a corrected answer, you simply do not take the limit right.